# Symfony routes with vue js

Tags: symfony, npm, vue.js

I created symfony app and now i'm gonna use vuejs well but with symfony routes. 
So my site will be multi-page. Therefore i have two controllers(/home and /login).

**Base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

    {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="{{ asset('build/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}

    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   delimiters: ['{(', ')}'],
     data: {
    message: ''
  },
});
```

Both controllers() should use app.js but with differents methods because in one Vue class, ie function "show" will show prompt in /home but in /login do nothing. How do connect vue with symfony

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using ? Because you can easily connect Vue.js with Symfony 4 (or 3.4) and yarn.This cloudways [article](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/symfony-vuejs-app/) explains it very well.

Comment: To be clear i want create multi-page site not spa;)

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the question straight, do you want to generate symfony routes in javascript?